# Angular Ng-if vs Ng-include

Tags: angularjs

Which is better to use on route views

```
obj = { contact:true,about:false };
<div ui-view="contact" ng-if="obj.contact"></div>
<div ui-view="about" ng-if="obj.about"></div>
```

or

```
<div ui-view="contact" ng-include="obj.contact"></div>
<div ui-view="about" ng-include="obj.about"></div>
```

Both do the same work bring template on the main html.

Among them which one is better to use for this case and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-include` is used to include an external HTML template, not to conditionally hide/show content. In this case, `ng-if` is correct.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: Yes, but as the docs state, it "Fetches, compiles, and includes an external HTML fragment". It doesn't do anything with a boolean except fail silently.

Comment: Not a problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include` has a significant performance hit.

Look at this:
[Avoiding ng-include for Elegance and Performance](http://www.codelord.net/2016/11/17/avoiding-ng-include-for-elegenace-and-performance/)